# Prevent overlay image from making underlying image unclickable

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML image with a "play button" image over it using standard position relative/absolute techniques for overlaying.

The underlying image has a hyperlink and the overlaying image does not. This however makes it impossible to click the hyperlink when the mouse is over the overlay image.

Is there any way to prevent the overlay image from "obstructing" the hyperlink in the underlying image, except from hyperlinking the overlay image as well?

Comment: Although the answer is probably `pointer-events:none`

Comment: It is. I didn't know about this one. Thanks! (I figured the question would be answerable without creating a full example.)

Answer (score -1):

Make use of the z-index.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

For example, set the image to z-index: -1 or the link to z-index: 1000